# Display the value of the first level of a sub field child of a Group [Layout] inside a Repeater [Layout] condition

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, acfpro

I have a **Repeater [Layout]** inside a **Group [Layout]** and I’m trying to display the **value** of a **sub field** **Text [Basic]** from a **child** of the **Group [Layout]** but it returns me nothing. It’s empty when I’m making a condition to make sure if the **Repeater [Layout]** is **True**. I want to display the **Group Name (Text [Basic])** when **Add File Repeater [Layout]** is **True**. Please check my **ACF Structure** below.

**ACF Structure**

- Marketing **Group [Layout]** (name: marketing)
- -- Group Name **Text [Basic]** (name: group_name)
- --- Add File **Repeater [Layout]** (name: add_file)

**This code is correct, I can see my group_name value**

```
<!-- Group [Layout] -->
<?php if (have_rows('marketing')): ?>
  <?php while (have_rows('marketing')): the_row(); ?>

    <?php
      /*--------------
      Extract ACF sub fields
      --------------*/

      // Text [Basic]
      $group_name = get_sub_field('group_name');
    ?>
    <li><?php the_sub_field('group_name');  ?></li>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?> <!-- End of Group [Layout] -->
```

**But when I add the condition here, I cannot access to the value of the_sub_field('group_name'); anymore en the repeater layout add_file is true, it's empty**

```
<!-- Group [Layout] -->
<?php if (have_rows('marketing')): ?>
  <?php while (have_rows('marketing')): the_row(); ?>

    <?php
      /*--------------
      Extract ACF sub fields
      --------------*/

      // Text [Basic]
      $group_name = get_sub_field('group_name');
    ?>
    <?php if (have_rows('add_file')): ?>
      <li><?php the_sub_field('group_name');  ?></li>
    <?php endif; ?>

  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?> <!-- End of Group [Layout] -->
```

Thank you! I cannot find the answer in the official ACF Documentation...

Comment: Would you be able to post the exported JSON for your field? That might help folks troubleshoot this in a live environment. See https://www.utilizewp.com/export-import-acf-field-group/ for assistance with export.